# Definition of "lisp form"?

Tags: lisp, scheme

What exactly the definition of a "Lisp form"?

As far as I know, it's "either an atom or a list that has a symbol as its first element".

But then, this (in Scheme) would not be a form:

```
((lambda () 42))  ;; The answer to Life, the Universe and Everything.
```

Because the first element of the list is itself another list. And after it's evaluated it will be a procedure (not a symbol).

I can find several different websites and tutorials talking about Lisp forms, but none which gives a complete and detailed definition. Where can I find one?

Comment: That's actually a valid lisp form and program.

I suppose my definition below will be as detailed as you get them, not sure if I forgot anything, but I believe it's exhaustive.

Comment: In Clojure: `((fn [] 42))`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

A lisp form is a lisp datum that is also a program, that is, it can be evaluated without an error.

```
(3 4 1)
```

Is a lisp datum, it's a list of 3, 4 and 1. This is not a form however as trying to evaluate it does not result into another datum. But rather an error.

```
3
```

Is a datum, and a form, also called a 'normal form' or a 'self-evaluating datum', it evaluates to itself.

```
(+ 3 4 1)
```

Is a *compound form*, evaluating it results into the *normal form* `8`.

Apart from normal forms and compound forms, compound forms can be subdivided into procedure calls and *special forms* (also called syntax) but more properly, the head of a special form is the syntax, as in:

```
(if (oddp 2) (print "me") (print "or me"))
```

This is a special form because it's head is syntax, and not a procedure, the *only* difference between procedure calls and special forms is that procedure calls see all of the arguments of the form as forms in itself and try to evaluate it first and special forms not necessarily do that. As we understand, only the second and fourth member of this compound form get evaluated, the first member is syntax, and the third is discarded in this case. As we know for instance:

```
((a 1) (b 2))
```

Is not a form in Common Lisp, it *could* be a valid form in Scheme, but only if the form `(a 1)` evaluates to a procedure datum. So:

```
(let ((a 1) (b 2)) (+ a b))
```

Is a *special form*, it does not evaluate its second member, and evaluates its third member in a different fashion than what would be expected if it was not a special form. That is, a and b as subforms of its third form have a different binding. `let` in this case is a syntactic keyword that signals the special form.

Note that it's quite possible that special forms still evaluate all of their arguments, they are still not procedure calls then, because their head is syntax, and procedures can be passed to other functions as arguments, syntax cannot, thus:

```
(func arg1 #'let)
```

Is an error, likewise:

```
(funcall let ((a 1) (b 2)) (+ a b))
```

Is an error, showing that it's different to a procedure call.

Comment: How would you declare your own `if` form, could you post an example of the syntax for a form `my-if`?

Comment: I'm afraid that `lisp datum` is not correct wording, as datum in Lisp is defined as 'An a-list is a list of pairs, the car of a pair is called the key, and the cdr is called datum' from p431 Common Lisp 2nd edition.

Comment: Thumbs up for explicitly referencing specific types of forms

Comment: One could argue that `if` is not syntax, but a function that demands that the interpreter perform lazy evaluation for once (whereas it generally doesn't for performance and simplicity reasons and reasons of determinism, especially for side-effects). But let's stay practical.

Comment: Is there a difference between 'form' and 'expression'? I mean all forms have values, even if nil, right?

Answer (score 14):

From the [common lisp hyperspec glossary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/26_glo_f.htm)

> **form n.** 1. any object meant to be evaluated. 2. a symbol, a compound form, or a self-evaluating object. 3. (for an operator, as in `<<operator>> form'') a compound form having that operator as its first element.`A quote form is a constant form.''