# Are clojure forms data or type?

Tags: clojure

I am beginning learning clojure. Coming majorly from Java and some scripting languages, the code as data part of clojure (and all functional languages, I assume) is not so clear.

Starting from the first pages of the book I see forms. And I see it mostly associated with data, like `#{1 2}`. But in some other places I saw `Boolean` labelled as `form`.

Now, I was under the assumption that `false` is a form of type `Boolean`, but I didn't see `type` being mentioned more than a few times, so I am confused.

Can someone give me a push to understand the concept of forms and also give me a push so that I can understand code as data part of the language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definition of "lisp form"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877371/definition-of-lisp-form)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clojure has forms because it is a [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)).

- A Clojure *form* is an element or data structure presented as part of
  a program.
- Clojure and other Lisps have forms in this sense.
- Most programming languages, apart from Lisps, do not: the structures
  used to compose program structure are nothing like the native data
  structures.
- Functional languages are no exception. Look, for example, at the
  [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_%28programming_language%29) family.

The rules for [evaluation](https://clojure.org/reference/evaluation) tell you how forms work.

- The payoff for using the native data structures to express program
  structure is that you can write programs that manipulate forms almost
  as easily as you can write any other kind.
- Such programs are called [macros](https://clojure.org/reference/macros).

For example, take a look at [the source for `and`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L834). You can't do this in Java.

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877371/definition-of-lisp-form#2877854) answers your question for Lisps in general.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are you saying form is data? or a literal may be?

Comment: @AmanuelNega Rather than tinker with this answer, I've had [another go](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43373834/1562315) at explaining the matter. Don't get obsessed with the question. Just play with the language and insight will grow in you.

Answer (score 3):

> Are clojure forms data or type?

- data

**A  Clojure *form* is a piece of code viewed as data.**

Clojure forms have a chemistry. The *elements* are things like

- numbers (`42`, `3.1416`, `22/7`)
- strings (`"1, 2, buckle my shoe."`)
- symbols (`a5`, `freds-white-teeth`), whatever they denote.

The *molecules* are things like

- expressions (`(+ 1 1)`,  `(reduce * (range 1 n))`)
- argument lists (`[f coll]`, `[[forename surname :as name]]`)

*The only structures used to bind molecular forms together are Clojure's own data structures*. This is what *code as data* means.

Clojure uses

- lists for expressions;
- vectors for argument lists (and binding forms in general);
- (maps for associative binding forms).

  (Leave these for now).

At the top level, we typically have `def` and `defn` forms. These can be many layers deep.

- `def` is a special form. It has its own evaluation rules.
- `defn` looks like a special form, but it isn't.

Because Clojure programs are written as Clojure data, we can write functions that

- take forms as arguments and
- return a form result.

---

The final piece of the jigsaw is that Clojure supplies a special mode of function, called a *macro*, that

- operates on its arguments as forms
- turns the call form into the form result.

This turns out to be a mechanism of great power. For example, `defn` is a macro that wraps a `fn` form inside a `def` form.  A cheap and cheerful analogue is

```
(defmacro my-defn [name & args-and-body]
  (list 'def name (cons 'fn (cons name args-and-body))))
```

The real `defn` is considerably more complicated. But this one is enough to cope with

```
(my-defn twice [n] (* 2 n))

(twice 3)
;6
```

We can see what's going on by doing

```
(macroexpand '(my-defn twice [n] (* 2 n)))
;(def twice (fn twice [n] (* 2 n)))
```

We can even define recursive functions:

```
(my-defn fact [n]
  (if (pos? n)
    (* n (fact (dec n)))
    1))

(map fact (range 1 5))
;(1 2 6 24)
```

---

- The above applies to any Lisp, not only to Clojure.
- Other Lisps use only lists for structuring forms.
- No other significant language has the *code as data* property.
- Functional languages are no exception: the ML family (ML, OCaml,
  Haskell, F#, ...) have fairly conventional syntax.